# Piping error with extra line and does not give a header

Tags: powershell

> 0001;Third Week;Every Monday 12am-2am
>   002;Third Week;Every Tuesday 8pm-10pm
>   003;Third Week;Every Monday 12am-2am

```
#Get the number of lines in a CSV file 
$Lines = (Import-Csv "C:\MM1.csv").count

#Import the CSV file 
$a = @(Import-CSV "C:\MM1.csv")

$month = Get-Date -Format MMMM

#loop around the end of the file    
for ($i=0; $i -le $lines; $i++) {
  $Servername = $a[$i].ServerName
  $week = $a[$i].Week    
  $dayweekString = [String]$a[$i].DayTime

  # This will help in getting the Day of the WeekDay String
  $dayweekString = ($dayweekString -split "\s+",(3))[(1)]

  #This will find the time Ex 2am or 8pm, it can be any time
  $DayNew = if ($Day -match "\d{1,2}Travelm") {$Matches[0]}

  #Format for Maintenance mode which can be fed into the SCOM MM Script.     
  $MaintenanceTime = get-date "$DayNew $month.$($_.$dayweekString).$year"
  write-host $Servername, $MaintenanceTime

  #Store all my data while in a for each loop
  New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
    ServerNameNew = $Servername
    TimeStamp = $MaintenanceTime
  } | Select-Object ServerNameNew,TimeStamp
} | Export-Csv -Path "C:\MM3.csv" -Append

# Error as extra Pipe
```

I am not able to pipe the output while in a loop with a header. Says Extra pipe and writes a extra line of TimeStamp Variable to the line.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to pipe the result of the `for` statement to another command. That's not supported. If you want to do that, you need to use a subexpression around the statement:

```
$( for(){} ) | ...
```

(The reason is that pipelines need an expression as their first element. And `for` is not an expression, it's a statement.)

However, in your case I'd replace the `for` with a simple pipeline iterating over the array, like this:

```
Import-CSV "C:\MM1.csv" | ForEach-Object {
  $Servername = $_.ServerName
  $week = $_.Week    
  $dayweekString = [String]$_.DayTime

  ...
}
```

Generally there is very rarely a reason to use explicit looping constructs in PowerShell. It leads to code that's awkward at best (because it resembles converted C# or VBScript code) and horrible at worst. Just don't do it.